# com.apple.PhotoIngestService crash crashes on Sierra

Tags: crash, macos, beta-seed-program

Every 5 or 10 minutes (or so) I see this window on my mac:

[image: com.apple.PhotoIngestService crash]

I cannot play games. Cannot write a song. It's highly distracting thing.

I searched for solution on the internet and found nothing.

macOS 10.12 Sierra Public Beta (16A313a)

Comment: I would suggest not running beta software on a primary system, for starters. The very nature of beta software is that it may work, or it may not work, or it may set your computer on fire and kick your dog.

Comment: @tubedogg this not solve my problem

Comment: I didn't say it would solve your immediate problem. But it's something to keep in mind for the future. Running beta software on a system that you are using as your main computer invites all sorts of problems, from crash messages like you are seeing now to loss of all of your data. It's not a good idea to run betas on a system you need to have functioning correctly on a regular basis.

Comment: @tubedogg using betas a few years, all is ok. Public beta is safe beta.

Answer (score -2):

Try restarting your Mac. I hope that will work.

Comment: try to login again and maybe you will suggest something helpful.